# Combination of Scatter HighChart with Polynomial Chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, regression, spline, scatter

I am trying a chart that combines two chart types in a one single-chart (spline & polynomial). When I merge both of them the chart stops working. If I them separately they work. Can I merge both chart in one using highchart?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'scatter',
      zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Polynomial regression - with extrapolation and different style'
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Source: Heinz  2003'
    },
    xAxis: {
      title: {
        enabled: true,
        text: 'Height (cm)'
      },
      startOnTick: true,
      endOnTick: true,
      showLastLabel: true
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Weight (kg)'
      }
    },
    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'left',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      x: 100,
      y: 70,
      floating: true,
      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    plotOptions: {
      scatter: {
        marker: {
          radius: 5,
          states: {
            hover: {
              enabled: true,
              lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
            }
          }
        },
        states: {
          hover: {
            marker: {
              enabled: false
            }
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
          pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'SplineChart',
        type: 'spline',
        marker: {
          enabled: true
        },
        tooltip: {
          pointFormatter: pointFormatter
        },
        data: [
          [1, 2],
          [1, 6],
          [3, 9],
        ]
      },
      {
        regression: true,
        regressionSettings: {
          type: 'polynomial',
          color: 'rgba(223, 183, 83, .9)',
          dashStyle: 'dash'
        },
        name: 'Test input',
        color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
        data: [
          [1, 1],
          [2, 3],
          [3, 9],

        ]

      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<script src="//rawgithub.com/phpepe/highcharts-regression/master/highcharts-regression.js?8">
</script>
Highcharts Regression
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: I see that you asked that question on Highcharts forum: https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/combine-spline-and-polynomial-regression-in-single-chart-t40488/ The answer is there.

Answer (score 0):

That's a reported [bug](https://github.com/streamlinesocial/highcharts-regression/issues/66). Anyway while using a transparent color for the    `spline` it works :

```
series: [{
    regression: true,
    regressionSettings: {
      type: 'polynomial',
      color: 'rgba(223, 183, 83, 0)', // transparent color
      dashStyle: 'dash'
    },
    name: 'SplineChart',
    type: 'spline',
    marker: {
      enabled: true
    },
    data: [
      [1, 2],
      [1, 6],
      [3, 9],
    ]
  }
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/y2eLye6b/19/)

Comment: its not working properly,they just plot the test point with scatter type ,and missing the functionality of polynomial type,One curve line is missing which is default behavior of polynomial chart.please see the example below